# Pandas timeseries indexing fails when the index is hierarchical

Tags: pandas, time-series

I tried the following code snippet.

```
In [84]:
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.parser import parse
​
rng = [datetime(2017,1,13), datetime(2017,1,14), datetime(2017,2,15), datetime(2017,2,16)]
​
s = Series([1,2,3,4], index=rng)
​s['2017/1']

Out[84]:
2017-01-13    1
2017-01-14    2
dtype: int64
```

As I expected, I could successfully retrieve only those items belonging to JAN by only specifying up to JAN like s['2017/1'].

Next time, I tried a bit extended version of the above code, where a hierarchical index was used instead:

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.parser import parse

rng1 = [datetime(2017,1,1), datetime(2017,1,1), datetime(2017,2,1), datetime(2017,2,1)]
rng2 = [datetime(2017,1,13), datetime(2017,1,14), datetime(2017,2,15), datetime(2017,2,16)]

midx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([rng1, rng2])

s = Series([1,2,3,4], index=midx)

s['2017/1']
```

The above code snippet, however, generates an error:
TypeError: unorderable types: int() > slice()

Would you give me some help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it is more complicated.

[`Partial string indexing on datetimeindex when part of a multiindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#partial-string-indexing-on-datetimeindex-when-part-of-a-multiindex) is implemented in `DataFrame` in `pandas 0.18.`

So if use:

```
rng1 = [pd.Timestamp(2017,5,1), pd.Timestamp(2017,5,1),
        pd.Timestamp(2017,6,1), pd.Timestamp(2017,6,1)]
rng2 = pd.date_range('2017-01-13', periods=2).tolist() +
       pd.date_range('2017-02-15', periods=2).tolist()
s = pd.Series([1,2,3,4], index=[rng1, rng2])
print (s)
2017-05-01  2017-01-13    1
            2017-01-14    2
2017-06-01  2017-02-15    3
            2017-02-16    4
```

Then for me works:

```
print (s.to_frame().loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, '2017/1'],:].squeeze())
2017-05-01  2017-01-13    1
            2017-01-14    2
Name: 0, dtype: int64

print (s.loc['2017/6'])
2017-06-01  2017-02-15    3
            2017-02-16    4
dtype: int64
```

But this return empty `Series`:

```
print (s.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, '2017/2']])
Series([], dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thank you @jezrael! Just using .loc() works perfectly! It appears that a Series with a multi-index is no longer treated as TimeSeries object even though the index contains time information. If it were, indexing into a row by using time string would have been a legitimate operation.

Previously I tried using .ix() but indexing by ix() fails. This is still strange to me.